# Delphi MT05.3 ecu

Tags: firmware

Hi I have a Honda IGX800 V twin engine with a Delphi MT05.3 ecu The engine has an idle of 1400 rpm
I would like to be able to gain access to the ecu and reduce the idle rpm to around 950 /1000 rpm
What would I need to access the ecu? and is there anyone who could help with reducing the idle rpm?
Any help suggestions ideas really would be appreciated thanks

Comment: [This](https://bitedit.ru/en/catalog/10) software claims that it can edit the calibration for your ECU

Comment: What controller are you using? Controls Inc?

Comment: I am not sure its just a Delphi MT05.3 ecu on a Honda IGX800 v twin Industrial engine